# How do i correctly add days to given date?

Tags: c++, mfc

I made this operator for class where I store date, it is supposed to add given number of days to date and convert it back to human format

```
CDate CDate::operator+(const int x)
{
    time_t t;
    struct tm tmp = {0};
    struct tm newtime = {0};
    tmp.tm_year = timeinfo.tm_year;
    tmp.tm_mon = timeinfo.tm_mon;
    tmp.tm_mday = timeinfo.tm_mday + x;
    t = mktime(&tmp);
    newtime = *(localtime(&t));
    return CDate(newtime.tm_year,newtime.tm_mon,newtime.tm_mday);
}
```

problem is it compute date 3 days higher that it should

concrete problem is, I have date 2000-01-02 (year-month-day) and i try to add 1500 days, expected result is 2004-02-10 but I am getting 2004-02-13

[check](http://www.timeanddate.com/date/dateadded.html?d1=02&m1=01&y1=2000&type=add&ay=&am=&aw=&ad=1500)

what am I doing wrong here?

my code: 
http://pastebin.com/wLxzTe3W

Comment: Can you post a minimal working code?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wLxzTe3W

Comment: Please edit your post and include the code there, not a link to it.

Comment: should i paste 70 lines?

Comment: Range for `tm_mday` is 1 t o 31. You cannot simply add `1500` to the day of month. You need to calculate a time stamp. For example, a day number of any given date. This is usually called the Julian day number, see for example the answer below. Other C time functions give you time stamp in second, but they have limited range.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Read the documentation, it´s valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors.

First, the `tm` passed to mktime is invalid: The year shouldn´t be the absolute year like `2000`, but the year difference from 1900, ie. `100` for 2000. With this problem corrected, I get `2004-02-12` as result (neither `2004-02-13` nor `2004-02-10`).

(On my computer, the program (without any changes) just crashes: mktime returns -1, localtime can´t handle it and returns an invalid pointer, which is used in the same line...)

Second, in the same struct, the day may be `1-31`, but the month only `0-11` (not `1-12`). Your `2000-01-02` is the second day of February, not January.

Knowing this, the result is correct (I´ll write the full year, but month starting from 0):
1500 days to add to `2000-01-02`:
2000 has 366 days (leap year), and we don´t need January and the first February day:
    `2000-01-02` + (366-31-1) days = `2001-00-01`, 1166 days to add left
Another 365 days makes `2002-00-01`, 801 days to add left
Another 365 days makes `2003-00-01`, 436 days to add left
Another 365 days makes `2004-00-01`, 71 days to add left
Another 31 of January makes `2004-01-01`, 40 days to add left
Another 29 of leap February makes `2004-02-01`, 11 days to add left
Another 11 added makes `2004-02-12`

Read http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/ carefully

Comment: well it really should result in 2004-02-10, as in link in my post , and this is also part of my homework where i know what result should i get, and reference date for this is also 2004-02-10

Comment: i was told method to do this is to add days to tm_mday then call mktime so it corrent everything, and then convert it back to fixed structure by using localtime()

Comment: @lllook Your first comment: Did you read my post, especially how I calculated that 02-12 is correct? And did your read the linked description of `tm`, where it cleary says that your code is wrong without subtracting 1900, and how the month has to be? If your teacher says 02-10 is correct, he either didn´t properly use mktime himself/herself, or is using a different calendar system (:p)

Comment: @lllook Your second comment:Yes, that´s ok. But again, read what I wrote, and read the description of `tm`.

Comment: And your "own" check site: http://www.timeanddate.com/date/dateadded.html?d1=2&m1=2&y1=2000&type=add&ay=&am=&aw=&ad=1500 If you want your teacher to be right, you need the correct date (second day of *January*)

Comment: you used starting date 2000-02-02 not 2000-01-02, i dont know maybe u got confused , maybe you are from america but this format is europeat when first is year then month and then day, starting from 01 being january, so i think you got your code right, you just used different starting point, could you show me your code?

Comment: @lllook Please **read** why I used this date. I didn´t write my answer to repeat everything in the comments. Yes I´m from Europe, but Europe/America is not the problem. Or at least say in words what start date you want.

Comment: thanks, so i need to subtract 1900 from year in constructor and subtract 1 from month to fix?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74490/discussion-between-deviantfan-and-lllook

Answer (score 0):

This is the algorithm for adding days to the date.

**Calculate day number from date.**

```
function g(y,m,d)

   m = (m + 9) % 12

   y = y - m/10

   return 365*y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400 + (m*306 + 5)/10 + ( d - 1 )
```

**To add no. of days in the date->**

g(y2,m2,d2) + no_of_days

**After this, you can convert your days back to date.**

```
    function d(g)
y = (10000*g + 14780)/3652425
ddd = g - (365*y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400)
if (ddd < 0) then
 y = y - 1
 ddd = g - (365*y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400)
 endif
mi = (100*ddd + 52)/3060
mm = (mi + 2)%12 + 1
y = y + (mi + 2)/12
dd = ddd - (mi*306 + 5)/10 + 1
return y, mm, dd
```

Comment: Link only answers are bad. The link could die in the future making your answer completely useless.

Comment: Yea...that I agree...But i personally feel that links of an algorithm is better than posting a code.

Comment: Still, i agree that links can die...will keep that in mind. :)

Comment: Including links in your answers is perfectly fine and even encouraged but _link only_ answers are not. See the _Provide context for links_ section in the SO [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: and isnt this exactly what mktime is supposed to do for us?

Comment: anyway thanks for answer, but i am curious why does my code not work